# How to add UILabel and UiImageView to a UIView inside table view cell programmatically?

Tags: swift, uitableview, uiimageview, uilabel

How can we add a label and a imageview inside a u UIView view which is placed inside a uitableviewcell. I want to build a chat screen like whatsapp, in-order to build the screen I want to append the label which is to display the chat messages and image view to the UIView which is placed inside the table view cell.

Comment: Why don't you search on https://www.cocoacontrols.com for some chat view etc

Comment: you can create a `tableviewcell` using storyboard and then place your `uiview` inside it and then you can place image and text over there

Comment: @swetanshkumar but what if there will be multiple images? So I want to append the label and image view so that according to the number of texts and images I can append these label and image views inside UIView.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do it fully programatically without storyboard you can watch this video for creating custom cells and views.

video by Brian Voong https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p_ak_ORr3KY&list=PL0dzCUj1L5JE1wErjzEyVqlvx92VN3DL5&index=4

or you can do this using storyboard

I mostly prefer mixing storyboard and code mainly because of adding/editing constraints I find much easier with storyboard.

video by Kilo Loco
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Wu5l4e5uW4w